e2e tests in node/typescript: injecting test container properties/cliento application
My typescript/node application connects to mongo and postgresql. I'm writing some e2e tests and I'm using testcontainers for this. However, the testcontainers run on a separate url, with potentially a different port, different username and pwd, etc
How do I get my application to connect to the test container instances of mongo and postgresql? The examples on the website https://node.testcontainers.org/modules/postgresql/ and https://node.testcontainers.org/modules/mongodb/ don't really illustrate this.
Here's a very close approximation to what my code looks like at the moment
import { app } from './app'
import request from 'supertest'
import { MongoDBContainer, StartedMongoDBContainer } from '@testcontainers/mongodb'
import { PostgreSqlContainer, StartedPostgreSqlContainer } from '@testcontainers/postgresql'

let mongo_container: StartedMongoDBContainer
let sql_container: StartedPostgreSqlContainer

beforeAll(async () => {
  mongo_container = await new MongoDBContainer().start()
  sql_container = await new PostgreSqlContainer().start()
}, 60000)

afterAll(async () => {
  mongo_container.stop()
  sql_container.stop()
})

test('should get from postgres', async () => {
  const res = await request(app).get('/from-postgres')
  expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200)
  expect(res.body).toMatchObject([ { fieldA: 3, fieldB: 2 } ])
})



app is the entrypoint to my program. Maybe the answer would be for that to depend on the mongo and postgresql containers/clients and then decide at runtime which to inject?
